# MySQL take from One Row and Create Two Rows

Tags: mysql, navicat

This might sound a little unorthodox but I haven't been able to find out if this even works.  I have a *MySQL* query that fills columns into a single row.

```
Select
      projectnumber,
      highnumber,
      lownumber
From
      Table1
WHERE
      project = 'THIS'
      and sequence = '0'
```

This would return on 1 row with 3 columns `"projectnumber"`, `"highnumber"`, `"lownumber"`.  I am needing to return 2 rows, both would have the same `"projectnumber"` but one row would have `"highnumber"`, and the second row would have the `"lownumber"` with an `"A"` appended to the end of it.

Is this even plausible?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ? Since it not really clear from the current explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use **UNION ALL** to "mix" two statements, and use [CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php) to append "A" to a cloumn:

```
SELECT projectnumber, highnumber FROM Table1 WHERE ...
UNION ALL SELECT projectnumber,CONCAT(lownumber,"A") FROM Table1 WHERE ...
```

Comment: I think you want `UNION ALL`, no deduping is required or mentioned.

Comment: @Arth Yes, use `UNION ALL` for better performance. I doubt there could be any duplicates (because of the concatenation).

Comment: How could you possibly know that? That might be the exact reason for the concatenation!

Comment: Aren't the duplicates tested after the concatenation takes place?

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplication in there if the person did what they were supposed to, but we know how that works out lol.  The concatenation is to show the difference in the High and Low Number, Low numbers will always have an A at the end.  and @Imashcha, yes they are tested after the concatenation.

Comment: Oh, there could be duplicates in the original table.

Comment: Is it possible to ad an "Order By" clause on this?